# On Windows git pull and clone for Google cloud repository pops credential manager dialog box

Tags: git, gcloud-cli

Pulling from an existing clone

```
git pull
```

or cloning Google cloud repository with gcloud

```
gcloud source repos clone default my_repo
```

produces the following dialog box: 
[image]

How do I configure git so that it uses gcloud credentials automatically?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you run

```
C:\> git config --list --system
credential.helper=manager
```

and get a setting for `credential.helper` like above, it will have precedence over gcloud installed credential helper.

You can unset it via (possibly as administrator)

```
C:\> git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Now

```
C:\> gcloud source repos clone default my_repo
```

should work and

```
C:\> cd my_repo
C:\my_repo> git config --list
```

should display

```
credential.helper="gcloud.cmd"
```

Comment: umm.. are there side effects to removing the --system credential.helper?

Comment: More recent git versions for windows started to set credential helper to Microsoft credential manager  https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows by default. If you working with Visual Studio or otherwise want to use this manager you can still set it for the repository you are working with, just don't use --system flag. That should remain unset.

Comment: I had something similar going on using OS X and Android Studio/Google Cloud Repository. It appears that there was a conflict with using the authentication within the .netrc Git file as well with the gcloud credential.helper. I am still investigating, but after deleting the .netrc file I was able to get authentication working. I hope this information is useful for someone else getting these types of errors.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I opened and modified 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig':

```
[credential]
    helper = gcloud.cmd
    old = manager
```

so that I had some notion of retention with my git config modifications..

Comment: You do not really want to set this helper globally or system wide. Just set it on the repository you are working with. Note that when you run `gcloud source repos clone default my_repo` it sets the helper just for the repository being cloned.

Comment: It worked for me, should hv installed gcloud fr single user.. wouldn't hv faces this problem

Comment: you could do this with the command `git config --add credential.helper "gcloud.cmd"`